# What is the default login session time out for SO?

Tags: support, login

I have been using Stack Overflow for some time, but only in recent months have I had to urge to give back and provide answers when I am able.

I am logged in through my phone, tablet, and a PC at work. I'm noticing that when I reload the site, I am prompted to log in. Is my token expiring prematurely, or could it be my work network discarding my session information?

Comment: In my experience, multiple months, 6-12 or something like that. If you're prompted to login a lot more often than that, it's probably due to a setting on the device or browser you're using.

Comment: I will have to blame our organization's settings, as I can't adjust many things on our browsers (yes, plural), and some sites (like youtube and reddit) are completely blocked.  Thank you for chiming in!

Comment: I have a technical write-up on what login entails https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/312956/158100 and it also mentions the cookies to expect. I have an  sgt cookie that expires for me in a month, the acct cookie in 6 months and the prov cookie is from a military ration, it doesn't go stale till 2055 ...